# I can't get my arraylist to print on separate lines...what am I doing wrong? JAVA

Tags: java

Hey all I would like my code to print like this:

John Smith, Math, 4.0, True

Jessica Snow, Communications, 4.0, false

Chris Christopherson, Science, 3.2, True

Currently it prints all on one line like this: 
John Smith, Math, 4.0, True, Jessica Snow, Communications, 4.0, false , Chris Christopherson, Science, 3.2, True

How can I get it to print on different lines?

```
    public static int addStudent(ArrayList students){
    Scanner inputStudents = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please Enter first name"); 
    String fname = inputStudents.nextLine();
    students.add(fname);


    System.out.println("Please Enter Last name");
    String lname = inputStudents.nextLine();
    students.add(lname);

    System.out.println("Please enter department of student's major");
    String department = inputStudents.nextLine();
    students.add(department);

    System.out.println("Please Enter GPA");
    Double gpa = inputStudents.nextDouble();
    students.add(gpa);

    System.out.println("Is the student involved in extracurriculars")     
   (true/false):");
    boolean extras = inputStudents.nextBoolean();
    students.add(extras);


    return 0;
```

Sorry I'm an idiot here is my print code:

```
}
public void print(){
    System.out.println(this.fname + " " +this.lname + " " + this.department+ "    
" + this.gpa + " "+ this.extras);
   }
}
```

Comment: where is your *printing* code ?

Comment: how is this code related to hte issue you describe?

Comment: This is a supposition (since you haven't given us the appropriate code for the question), but are you using `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`?

Comment: Sorry!  I'm an idiot, I provided my print code.

Answer (score -1):

Iterate the ArrayList via for loop after you've collected the students in your function return. In this case, here is a sample loop:

```
students.forEach((name) -> {
System.out.println(name);
});
```

Also, make the function null since you don't necessarily return anything other than 0 unless you're planning to do something.

EDIT: fixed.

Comment: For the *love of the compilers*, at least fix the condition of the loop!

Comment: I guess you are assuming that student class's toString method is overridden.

Comment: I'd guess so. He didn't even gave proper info on his code. I'm just giving out hints, man.